# Using PayPal REST API, is it possible to change any attributes of a Billing Plan that already has Agreements?

Tags: paypal

My question is whether I am allowed to change any attributes of a Billing Plan that already has Agreements associated with it. (I understand that I am not allowed to change the terms of the Plan i.e. payment_definitions - amount, frequency etc..)

It seems that some of the fields of a Plan should be allowed to be updated even if they have Agreements.

For example, my initial monthly plan was $10 a month and I don't want to offer that plan anymore.  I would like to update the Billing Plan to make its state "INACTIVE".  This will not affect users who already have an Agreement with this plan, but will allow me to go ahead and offer a $12 monthly plan to new users who sign up.

Another example might be if I want to change the name or description of the plan.  This would not affect the terms that the user agreed to, so am I allowed to update it?

Comment: I'm also looking for answer to this question. I want to know what should I do if my payable amount or frequency for a billing plan changes?